# I can't figure out how to install PyQt5

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

I am not a pro, just an amateur enthusiast trying to level up. Apparently I am missing something when it comes to installing PyQt5. In the effort to do so I have gone through several versions of python, and screwed up PyCharm such that it basically doesn't run even my old stuff.

I currently have a 64 bit Python 3.5 and a 32 bit python 3.6 installed. I couldn't figure out where the install file on the latest PyQt5 was, so I used an exe version: `PyQt5-5.6-gpl-Py3.5-Qt5.6.0-x32-2.exe`

All appeared well, but after this step PyCharm wouldn't work, so I got it to rediscover Python again, but now I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/RFC/PycharmProjects/PyQt_learning/test.py", line 2, in <module>
    from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt5'
```

So, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I suggest you do is uninstall and redownload the exe. Also after checking the website I have discovered that this version of PyQt5 is only compatible with Python 3.5 not 3.6.